# Detect timezone abbreviation from a given date object using Angular2 or moment js or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, date, timezone, momentjs

I have response coming from backend as "2020-09-05T07:00:00-08:00" (-08:00 at the end is basically GMT-8:00). So I need a way to detect the timezone of a given date object.

```
For example, GMT, UTC, PST, MST, CST, EST, etc...
```

I know moment.tz.guess() will return browsers timezone. But I'm looking to detect timezone from a specific date object

Comment: You can't do that as Date objects don't have **any** timezone information. If all you have is the offset, you can't reverse engineer the timezone abbreviation because you can't reliably determine the timezone name. Add to that that neither names nor abbreviations are standardised, so you might get different names and/or abbreviations (or none at all) depending on implementation. :-(

Comment: E.g. there are at least 6 different [names and abbreviations for UTC+10](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc+10): AEST, CHST, CHUT, DDUT, PGT, VLAT and at least 3 for [UTC-8](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc-8):  CIST, PST, AKDT where PST can be either (US) Pacific Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time.

Comment: @RobG thanks! Can i atleast get the list of timezones? for that specific date and time?

Comment: There's a link in my comment to [24timezones.com](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc-8), there are many other sites with similar resources. As the names and abbreviations aren't standardised, there is no definitive resource.